# how to hide wysihtml5 editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5

I need to hide and show the editor based on event.

I initiate the editor. then, i try to hide using the code:

```
$('#textare').hide();
```

but it doesn't work, since it as I think initiate iframe

so how can I show and hide editor

**Update:** I'm sorry forget to add editor name.. I use **wysihtml5**. 
I think the way that editor work is hide the textarea and make iframe
so the above text couldent hide the editor.

Comment: Please show some html. also, do you get any error messages via console?- could you have mistyped `$('#textarea')`

Comment: Go to your javascript console (Chrome: [F12]) and look for errors ...

Comment: is that a direct copy and paste? does the textarea actually have an id of textare? With the typo....

Comment: this is an example of editor: http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

Comment: You need to hide the editable area or you want to disable editing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textarea should already be hidden since it will only be used as a fallback. The editor itself is contained in an iframe with class `wysihtml5-sandbox`. So this should toggle the editor

```
$(".wysihtml5-sandbox").hide()
```

Comment: you get the idea, but still two problem: the toolbar didn't hide, the next i have multiple editor on same page.

Comment: I won't do all the work for you. The toolbar is just another item (class `wysihtml5-editor-toolbar`) to hide. Which editor to hide are also just some lines of code which has nothing to do with this specific problem :)

Comment: thanks. What make me confuse the iframe genrated by plug-in, but know I get the idea. but really the solution for multiple instance is not clear, since i couldn't find any ID or something....